# Loop over two generator together

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, generator, yield

I have two generators say `A()` and `B()`. I want to iterate over both the generators together. Something like:

```
for a,b in A(),B():    # I know this is wrong
    #do processing on a and b
```

One way is to store the results of both the functions in lists and then loop over the merged list. Something like this:

```
resA = [a for a in A()]
resB = [b for b in B()]
for a,b in zip(resA, resB):
    #do stuff
```

*If you are wondering, then yes both the functions yield equal number of value.*

But I can't use this approach because `A()/B()` returns so many values. Storing them in a list would exhaust the memory, that's why I am using generators.

**Is there any way to loop over both the generators at once?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You were *almost* there. In Python 3, just pass the generators to `zip()`:

```
for a, b in zip(A(), B()):
```

`zip()` takes any iterable, not just lists. It will consume the generators one by one.

In Python 2, use [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
from itertools import izip

for a, b in izip(A(), B()):
```

As an aside, turning a generator into a list is as simple as `list(generator)`; no need to use a list comprehension there.

Comment: Purely academically, if `A()` yields 1,2,3 and `B()` yields 4,5,6 does this produce `a,b = (1,4)`, `(1,5)`, `(1,6)`, `(2,4)`, `(2,5)` ... `(3,6)` ?

Comment: @adsmith: It does not. It produces `(1, 4)`, `(2, 5)` and `(3, 6)`. You are thinking of `itertools.product()`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
from itertools import izip

for a, b in izip(A(), B()):
```

From the docs:

> Like `zip()` except that it returns an iterator instead of a list.

So this way you never create a `list`, either of `A()`, `B()` or the `izip()`.

Note that in Python 3's basic `zip` is like Python 2.x's `itertools.izip`.

Comment: in this case both the lists has to have equal number of items, and if second list has more items it will not be printed

Comment: @san to be specific, whichever argument is longer will be truncated to the length of the shortest. If you need to process pairs, that is necessary. If you want to get as many items as possible, there is `[i]zip_longest`, although if one of your arguments is e.g. an infinitely long generator you will have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zip function to transform the two lists generated into an list of tuples, so you can use the way you want:

```
for a,b in zip(A(), B()):
    pass
```